# Find the limit of the given function?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $a>$ 0 and $k \in \mathbb N$. Evaluate

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a^{-nk}\prod_{j=1}^k(a+\frac{j}{n})^n.$$

How is this accomplished?

Comment: What have you done so far in solving the problem?

Comment: First steps might be: (1) Note that $a^{-nk} = \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{a^n};\;$ (2) distribute the factors; (3) simplify $\frac{1}{a^n}(a+\frac{j}{n})^n$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/643454/

Answer (score 1):

We rely on the continuity of the product function $\prod_{j=1}^k\cdot$ to pass the limit inside, then convert the product of exponentials into an exponential of a sum.  \begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{-nk}\prod_{j=1}^k\Big(a+\frac{j}{n}\Big)^n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=1}^k\Big(a+\frac{j}{n}\Big)^na^{-n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=1}^k\Big(1+\frac{j}{an}\Big)^n\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^k \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1+\frac{j}{an}\Big)^n\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^k e^{j/a}\\
&=\exp\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{j}{a}\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{a}\sum_{j=1}^k j\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg(\frac{k(k+1)}{2a}\bigg).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a^{-nk}\prod_{j=1}^k\left(a+\frac{j}{n}\right)^n=
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \prod_{j=1}^k\left(1+\frac{j}{an}\right)^n=\prod_{j=1}^k
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{j}{an}\right)^n=\prod_{j=1}^k\mathrm{e}^{j/a}.
$$

Comment: Actually you can further simplify the expression to a single exponential.